# TypeScript React Define a prop only if other prop already defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have an interface of input like

```
export interface IInputProps {
  name: string
  type: React.HTMLInputTypeAttribute
  register: any
  watch?: string
  .
  .
  .
  label?: string
  additionalButton?: string
  additionalButtonCallback?: () => void
}
```

and I want to have both `additionalButton` and `additionalButtonCallback` together, but also have a possibility not to define them at all.

For example

```
        <InputComponent
          register={register}
          name="newEmail"
          type="text"
          label="New Email"
          required="Please, enter your email"
          error={errors.newEmail}
        />
```

Possible to write without `additionalButton` and `additionalButtonCallback`

```
        <InputComponent
          register={register}
          name="newEmailCode"
          type="text"
          label="New Email Verification Code"
          additionalButton="Get code" <-- Causes error, additionalButtonCallback is not defined
        />
```